# Create a simple WYSIWYG web editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wysiwyg

I'm new to web development and I've never worked on web-related
projects before, but in this scholar project thing, I have to create a WYSIWYG web editor from scratch.

Till now I've learned HTML, CSS and javascipt and I intent to attack Jquery and also to READ the source code of a web editor (like TinyMce) to get me going and have an idea of what I have to do.
     The problem is that TinyMce is way too complicated for me, I need a web editor that is much simpler than that. so if u could help me with a name I would be very grateful : )

Comment: i dont like tinyMce, had trouble when i first used it. I used CKEditor instead. It is very difficult to create a WYSIWYG editor, i suggest you take the time to learn. Most of the good ones out there are well documented these days,

Comment: start with a much simpler one than tinymce or ckeditor.This is not a trivial task for someone with limited knowledge of the DOM

Comment: Thing is, there are no simple editors out there.. In fact these complex programs will confuse you if you look at them since they contain loads of smaller plugins (tinyMCE). Start simpler with an HTML element.

Comment: [markItUp editor](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/), what about this one ? is it simple enough ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advise is to start building something simple and small, instead of trying to understand some editor's code.

Basically you just need a textarea and a bunch of buttons (since textarea is difficoult to format, we use an [editable](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp) div, that allows formatting text):

```
<div id="fake_textarea" contenteditable></div>
<button id="jBold" value="B">
```

Then with some jQuery magic, you can 'boldify' selected text when clicking the button. The simplest way is the `execCommand('bold')`[method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand), that finds the selected text and makes it bold (**EDIT: execCommand got deprecated!!**)

```
$('#jBold').click(function () {
    document.execCommand('bold');
});
```

In the following snippet you can find a basic example. You can easily add some other button, like italic or underline.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#jBold').click(function() {
    document.execCommand('bold');
  });
});
```

```css
#fake_textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='fake_textarea' contenteditable>
  Highlight some text and click the button to make it bold...
  <br>Or write your own text
</div>
<button id="jBold"><b>B</b></button>
```

Comment: Wha? How does `document.execCommand` work? Some explanation would be good.

Comment: hey, thank u very much for ur suggestion. but the thing is that I've found this [link](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) and I think I can understand the source code of this editor,

Comment: do u think that I can build something like this editor(markitUp editor) ?